# How to connect to beaglebone black

Tags: beagleboneblack

I've bought beaglebone black last day and tried to connect with it using USB. As i have read it comes with preinstalled Linux Distro which runs at 192.168.7.2 and we can access it using ssh. But i'm not able to connect. Using start.html provided with device, i have run the script (i'm using Linux not window) for driver installation which actually adds some udev rules. I found out that `product id` and `vendor id` provided in script isn't matching with that of device (i checked using `lsusb`). i'm attaching `lsusb` output of my device. You can find the online script for linux (driver installation) at http://beagleboard.org/static/Drivers/Linux/FTDI/mkudevrule.sh. Please let me know how can i connect with my device

========================lsusb=========================

```
Bus 002 Device 013: ID 1d6b:0104 Linux Foundation Multifunction Composite Gadget
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass          239 Miscellaneous Device
  bDeviceSubClass         2 ?
  bDeviceProtocol         1 Interface Association
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x1d6b Linux Foundation
  idProduct          0x0104 Multifunction Composite Gadget
  bcdDevice            3.08
  iManufacturer           2 Circuitco
  iProduct                3 BeagleBoneBlack
  iSerial                 4 6A-0414BBBK1966
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength          164
    bNumInterfaces          5
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          5 Multifunction with RNDIS
    bmAttributes         0xc0
      Self Powered
    MaxPower                2mA
    Interface Association:
      bLength                 8
      bDescriptorType        11
      bFirstInterface         0
      bInterfaceCount         2
      bFunctionClass          2 Communications
      bFunctionSubClass       6 Ethernet Networking
      bFunctionProtocol       0 
      iFunction               9 RNDIS
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         2 Communications
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Abstract (modem)
      bInterfaceProtocol    255 Vendor Specific (MSFT RNDIS?)
      iInterface              7 RNDIS Communications Control
      CDC Header:
        bcdCDC               1.10
      CDC Call Management:
        bmCapabilities       0x00
        bDataInterface          1
      CDC ACM:
        bmCapabilities       0x00
      CDC Union:
        bMasterInterface        0
        bSlaveInterface         1 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0008  1x 8 bytes
        bInterval               9
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass        10 CDC Data
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 Unused
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              8 RNDIS Ethernet Data
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
    Interface Association:
      bLength                 8
      bDescriptorType        11
      bFirstInterface         2
      bInterfaceCount         2
      bFunctionClass          2 Communications
      bFunctionSubClass       2 Abstract (modem)
      bFunctionProtocol       1 AT-commands (v.25ter)
      iFunction              12 CDC Serial
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        2
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         2 Communications
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Abstract (modem)
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 AT-commands (v.25ter)
      iInterface             10 CDC Abstract Control Model (ACM)
      CDC Header:
        bcdCDC               1.10
      CDC Call Management:
        bmCapabilities       0x00
        bDataInterface          3
      CDC ACM:
        bmCapabilities       0x02
          line coding and serial state
      CDC Union:
        bMasterInterface        2
        bSlaveInterface         3 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x84  EP 4 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x000a  1x 10 bytes
        bInterval               9
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        3
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass        10 CDC Data
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 Unused
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface             11 CDC ACM Data
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        4
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         8 Mass Storage
      bInterfaceSubClass      6 SCSI
      bInterfaceProtocol     80 Bulk-Only
      iInterface              1 Mass Storage
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x85  EP 5 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x03  EP 3 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               1
Device Qualifier (for other device speed):
  bLength                10
  bDescriptorType         6
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass          239 Miscellaneous Device
  bDeviceSubClass         2 ?
  bDeviceProtocol         1 Interface Association
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  bNumConfigurations      1
Device Status:     0x0001
  Self Powered
```

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue yet? If not; what is the message you get when you attempt to ssh to the beagle?

Comment: One way to connect is to use a USB-Serial cable. You can find them here. http://elinux.org/Beagleboard:BeagleBone_Black_Accessories#Serial_Debug_Cables. After you have a USB-Serial cable connected execute the following command from xterm "screen /dev/ttyUSB0 115200". You can find more information here. http://shallowsky.com/blog/hardware/talking-to-beaglebone.html

Answer (score 0):

Its simple just open your web browser chrome or mozilla fire fox and enter the ip in the title bar. Thats it you will get onto it. And comming to ssh if you specify the command you entered i can provide you the resolution.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. Making an auto ethernet connection to eth1 will make it possible to connect most of the times (sometimes you have to disconnect and connect several times!), but the best way is to use `screen` command.

`sudo screen /dev/ttyACM0 115200`

(it can be ttyACM* or ttyUSB*, you have to check).
You can login and connect this way. Not sure if it solves your problem though. Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you dont have to connect to ethernet. You can use ethernet over usb by connecting the mini usb to your system. Linux usually dont require any drivers to be installed..
After you connect just open your browser and go on 192.168.7.2(default)

Sometimes you have to hold the S2 button(closest to the memory card slot) before you plug the usb cable. Also remove ethernet connection.